# How can I redirect a file in a subprocess using "<"?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have looked at other similar questions but was not able to find an answer to my question.

This is what I want to execute:

```
gagner -arg1 < file1
```

This is my code so far:

```
filePath = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("All files", "*.*")])

fileNameStringForm = (basename(filePath ))
fileNameByteForm = fileNameStringForm.encode(encoding='utf-8')

process = subprocess.Popen(['gagner','-arg1'], shell = True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

stdout, stderr = process .communicate(fileNameByteForm) 

stringOutput = stdout.decode('utf-8')
print(stringOutput)
```

Currently if I run this code, nothing happens. I get no errors, but no output is also printed.

Could someone please show me how I can execute the linux command above using python.

Comment: BTW, typo note: You almost certainly wanted `stringOutput = stdout.decode('utf-8')` not `urf-8`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger TY for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't pass the name to the process (it expects to read file *data* from `stdin`, not a file *name*); instead, pass the file handle itself (or using `PIPE`, the raw file data).

So you could just do:

```
with open(fileNameStringForm, 'rb') as f:
    process = subprocess.Popen(['gagner','-arg1'], stdin=f, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```

or somewhat less efficiently (since Python has to read it, then write it, instead of letting the process read directly):

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['gagner','-arg1'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
with open(fileNameStringForm, 'rb') as f:
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate(f.read())
```

Note that I removed `shell=True` from both invocations; using `list` command form removes the need, and it's both faster, safer and more stable to avoid the shell wrapping.

Comment: Could you please explain what does "with open(fileNameStringForm, 'rb') as f:" do? Im pretty new to python, sorry if this is obvious.

Comment: Just want to make sure, so is the variable fileNameByteForm not needed anmore? Also, used your second method and it tells me "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gagner'
"

Comment: I used your second method and it tells me `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gagner'`.

Comment: @J.Doe: If `gagner` isn't in your `PATH`, you'd need to provide a relative or absolute path to find it, not just the plain name. For your other questions, take a look at the [`open` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) and the [`with` statement docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) (you may want to click the links to other docs scattered around on `with`). `fileNameByteForm` was never needed unless you had a file whose name was not expressed in your login's locale for some reason.

Comment: @J.Doe: Yes, but if `.` isn't in your `PATH` (generally recommended to avoid that, since it opens security holes), then an unqualified `gagner` won't find it. You'd need to use `./gagner` (or if it's in the same folder as the script, but that is not the working directory, you'd either need an absolute path, or you'd need to construct one with something like `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'gagner')`).